# Flutter e-commerce app auto debit in wallet after purchase

Tags: flutter, dart, automation, e-commerce, wallet

I have made an e-commerce app with flutter and last thing which is remaining is I want to auto debit 1% of order amount automatically added to my store wallet. But have no idea how to do this. Please help if someone know the trick.

I have tried 2-3 methods but none worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.